# Models in Android

Tags: java, android, dry

I'm coming from a strong PHP background, where in MVC, we had models that took care of all our data validation and processing needs. Now I'm trying to see if this can be done in Android.

I have a function that verifies a phone number, and I'm going to need the same functionality in 2 or more activities. I'd like to put this in a model I could share around. How do I go about doing this in android?

Thanks!

**Here is a concrete example:**

I have 2 public Activities.

- Each one of them must have the ability to launch a third application, if this is the first time the application is run.
- Each one must launch a seperate thread that checks if this version is supported, by checking against a remote server.

So, how do I go about keeping my code DRY in this case? Do I extend the application?

Answer (score 4):

You can create separate class PhoneNumber:

```
class PhoneNumber {

    public static boolean verify(String phoneNumber) {
        // your verification functionality
    }

}
```

and then use this method:

```
if (PhoneNumber.verify(phoneNumber)) {
    // your code
}
```

Simply import you class:

```
import PhoneNumber; // or full path to you class in package
```

Comment: Yes, that much I'm aware of, but what about getting system specific data from within those models? Like getting the phone-number from OS and then comparing it to a passed number? Wouldn't this fail?

Comment: For getting phone number from phone contacts, you can use something like this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but will not extending an Android class allow me to use this model elsewhere? Because I tried getting a function from a class that extended Activity, but that seemed not to work.

Comment: Just pass the context to your static function.  Then you can call yourContext.getContentResolver() to query contacts.